# Why does the Continue VS Code extension continue to run in the background even after closing VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ram

idk if there is an automatic solution for this or i need to do it manually every time in the task manager but this vs code extension is not closing whenever i close vs code i found it there eating my beloved ram storage
any idea?

i try to look for a solution but no one seem to have this problem or maybe this extension is not famous as i think its
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Continue.continue
link for this extension

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Seems like you're leaking a process you launch from the extension, but without seeing the code we can't know for sure.

Comment: im so sorry guys its my first time asking 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Continue.continue
this is the link for the extension 
and no there is no code the extension is working fine everything is good except when i check task manager i see that this extension server is still working (continueservice.exe)
that is my problem ,thanks

Comment: @OussamaBensaidi Please [edit] so that all the details are in the question. Specifically, *"when i check task manager i see that this extension server is still working (continueservice.exe)"*

Comment: This seems to be covered on the extension page: *"To allow quick startup times, the server will run on your computer in the background, even while not using Continue."* In the future, please start with your own research. That's one of the tips in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be [documented behaviour](https://github.com/continuedev/continue/blob/main/extensions/vscode/README.md#continue-server):

> The Continue server is a Python server that runs locally on your computer allowing complete privacy. It handles indexing the codebase, constructing prompts, storing and loading configuration, and more. To allow quick startup times, the server will run on your computer in the background, even while not using Continue. If you'd like to stop the server yourself, the process runs on port 65432, and also depends on an instance of Meilisearch running on port 7700.

Comment: this seems to be the solution thanks